# How to press PageDown button in Sikuli?

Tags: sikuli

In my project I need to press <kbd>Page Down</kbd> button using Sikuli. Currently, I am using below line of code but it does not work:

```
screen.type(Key.PAGE_DOWN);
```

Comment: This line should work just fine. Your problem is probably elsewhere. Paste full code and the error you are getting. The provided information is insufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you push this button manually? Does it work?
Try to do it like this:

```
screen.keyDown(Key.PAGE_DOWN);
Thread.sleep(500);
screen.keyUp();
```

Also make sure that this window is focused

Comment: firstly thx, Mikhail.I try the above code but it not show me the actually screen,it show different screen.

Comment: when I manually press from Keyword "PAGE-DOWN" button it show correct screen,but when I do it through "Sikuli" it show different scrren.